# Is it possible in Visual Studio to build a project while debugging another project in the same solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Let's say I have the two following projects in a Visual Studio solution:

**ProjectA**, which outputs an arbitrary file that is not an executable.

**ProjectB**, which outputs an executable.

These two are not dependant on each other in any way. **ProjectB** is the startup project.

Now, if I run **ProjectB** and try to rebuild **ProjectA** during the debugging of **ProjectB** the debugger will force me to abort the current debugging session before proceeding with the build.

Is there a way to not abort debugging and still rebuild **ProjectA** during runtime without having to resort to multiple solutions?

Comment: I would like to know as well.